# Can we reconstruct a DE from its general solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we think of a differential equation as being a 'problem' and the set of all solutions to the DE as being the 'general solution,' then my question is this:

**Question:**

*Under what circumstances can we reconstruct the problem from the general solution?*

---

Lets make that more precise.

**Definition 1**. Whenever $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^n \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function, define that $S(f)$ is the set of all solutions $y : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to the ODE

$$y^{(n)}(x) = f(y^{(n-1)}(x),\cdots,y^{(0)}(x),x),\quad x \in X.$$

We can think of $f$ as the 'problem' and $S(f)$ as the 'general solution.'

**Question:**

What conditions need to be added to $f$ and/or $X$ in the above definition to guarantee that the solution function $S$ is an injection? (That is, one-to-one).

*Remark*. This is still a rather imprecise way of formulating the question, and any suggestions for making it better would be appreciated. Please leave a comment!

Comment: Perhaps it's better to use the definition: whenever $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ and $F:\mathbb R^{n+1}\times X\to R$ is a function, define $S(f)$ to be the set of all solutions $y:X\to R$ to the ODE $$0 = f(y^{(n)}(x),\cdots,y^{(0)}(x),x),\quad x \in X.$$ to include implicit ODE's.  Then again, it's probably smarter to start small.

Comment: @user18921 Notice the solution set $f(x) = c$ for $c$ a constant is shared by at least $k \frac{dy}{dx}=0$ where $k \neq 0$. To obtain unique 'Problem' you'll have to deal with this issue.Nice question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I originally thought that, too. However, all hope of uniqueness vanishes in a puff of smoke for the implicit case. For instance, replacing $f(*)$ in your equation with $2f(*)$ yields an equivalent equation, which will therefore have the same solutions.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook, I think the question as formulated avoids that particular problem. Notice that $k \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ isn't in the form $y^{(n)}(x) = f(y^{(n-1)}(x),\cdots,y^{(0)}(x),x).$ Indeed, for $k \neq 0$, your equation is equivalent to $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0.$

Comment: @user18921 good point. Also, a good reason to not attempt the implicit formulation I suppose. It's sort of a monic condition.

Answer (score 3):

The following is an attempt to use Lie's symmetry method in reverse. I have no idea if it works in general, or if the DE you get is unique.

Suppose you have $y = g(x;\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3, ..., \theta_n)$, where each $\theta_i$ is a constant of integration parametrizing the solution. Find $y_{\theta_1}$

We want to find a change of coordinates $y\rightarrow h(y,x) = u$ such that $u_{\theta_1}=1$. If we can do this, then we can use our solution to write $u$ as a function of $x$ and the various constants of integration. However, since $u_{\theta_1}=1$, we expect that $u$ will take the form $u = g_2(x;\theta_2,\theta_3,...,\theta_n)+\theta_1$. We will then take the derivative w.r.t. $x$ to eliminate the $\theta_1$ dependence. This will be done recursively until all constants of integration are eliminated.

$$
u_{\theta_1} = h_yy_{\theta_1} = 1\\
h_y = y_{\theta_1}^{-1}
$$

Let's try an example. $y = \theta_2\ln(x)+\theta_1+\frac{x^2}{4}$

Notice, we already have something of the form $g(x;\theta_2,\theta_3,...,\theta_n)+\theta_1$, so we can skip the first step (i.e. finding a suitable coordinate change) and just differentiate.

$$y' = y_1 = \frac{\theta_2}{x}+\frac{x}{2}$$

Now we apply the method outlined above.

$$\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial \theta_2} = \frac{1}{x} \implies h_{y_1} = x \implies h(x,y_1) = xy_1
$$

Note, this $h$ is not uniquely defined. Using this $h$, we let $ y_1 = \frac{u}{x}$. The DE becomes
$$u = \frac{1}{2}x^2+\theta_2 \implies u' = x$$

Back-substitute.

$$
\frac{dy_1}{dx} = \frac{u'}{x}-\frac{u}{x^2} = 1 - \frac{y_1}{x}
$$

And $y_1=y'$, so we obtain

$$
y'' = 1-\frac{y'}{x}$$

This fits the original solution.

Comment: This is probably slightly tangential to the actual question, buts its also very cool. You've basically made the next step, giving a method for explicitly constructing the original problem, given a general solution. Altogether a very interesting answer!

Comment: I realize it's a little off topic. Understanding when this method fails could be useful, though.